# How can I end the cell's edit and submit the new value when the user clicks on another control?

Tags: vb.net, events, datagridview, edit

When i type a value in a cell I want to submit this new value by clicking on another control. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `DataGridView1.EndEdit()` before the save code in the button save.

Comment: hi mate. My problem is that the cellEndEdit event is not being raised when I click outside the datagridview. Also I am talking about a simple datagridview without database as a data source.

Comment: I have no code to handle this case. I was thinking of triggering the cellEndEdit event manually when the datagridview loses focus. What do you think?

Comment: I gave u the answer bro, use the above code, just put ur database connection string and sql string to update the database

Comment: or where u want to submit ur edited data? to database or something else?

Comment: Thanks man but this solution is not what I am looking for. I explained in the first comment.

Comment: I just want to submit the value to the cell. I can do this by hitting "enter" button or "tab" or clicking in another cell. Now I want to additionaly do this if the user clicks outside the datagridview.

Comment: (submit the value to the cell), the value u mentioned comes from where?

Comment: sorry. the value comes from characters I enter in the cell using the keyboard

Comment: I am sorry Man,  think I'm confused here or my english too bad to understand what u want, I didn't understand how u want to submit the value to cell if the value already comes from the cell! sorry man again, or u can give my an exact example of what u want step by step.

Comment: Ok. I have a datagridview. I also have a save button that triggers a mechanism which reads the datagridview and saves the data in a xml file.

Comment: I can enter some text in a blank cell by selecting it and typing something. When i start typing a pencil icon appears on the very left of the row that means i am editing the cell. When i stop typing the pencil icon is still there. If i hit "Enter" the value i typed is being "submitted" to the cell and the pencil icon dissappears. BUT If i click the save button without clicking "Enter" first, the value is not being submitted and the mechanism doesn't save this value.

Comment: ok try in Save button to but this DataGridView1.EndEdit() it must be at the first line of the button click event, which above the save code

Comment: Worked perfectly! sorry for the wrong question! and thank you!

Comment: I changed the question so this may help someone else. In exchange for your help i'd like to give the answer sign to you. if you are interested tell me how are we gonna do this.

Comment: ok good to hear that, just mark my answer as the correct answer, i've already changed my answer.if u don't know how just click on right sign next to my answer